# Magento Community Edition ver 1.9.2.0 download source

Tags: magento-community

To download Magento Community Edition ver 1.9.2.0, you need to login to magentocommerce.com.

I can't login, because I don't know my password, and I can't retrieve my password, because the password reset email never reaches my Gmail account (not in spam either). When I ask Magento support for help, they say there is no such account corresponding to my email, but when I try to register, it says my email is already registered. I haven't heard from them for about 10 days.

**Long story short**, is this https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror a reliable copy of Magento 1.9.2?

Answer (score 1):

> **Disclaimer** : Below Content is purely my opinion. Just putting my
>   thoughts here

This question is purely opinion based. But I have a short solution for you. Create another email address and then register with that new email address in magentocommerce.com. Problem solved.

### About The Repository

Normally I use that repository for quick reference purpose for different versions. If you ask me, whether you can rely on that, then answer is yes if you are going to use that for development purpose and no for a production purpose. This is because even if I know that repo is genuine, it is not an offical repository of Magento.

Comment: Thanks Rajeev. Magento just got back to me with some help. They've created my account, and I've received the password reset email.

Comment: Great steve. If this answer helped you, then you can accept.